# Problem with Custom Post Type Categories

Tags: categories, customization

Before I proceed on writing anything just have a look the following images. (snapshots)

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have one custom post type by name 'questions' just like we have 'posts/pages'. If you look at the image one, you can find that. And I found categories in that too. When I click on one of the categories in that (like Apostasy which has 1 article), I found that in categories of the questions (have a look at the image-2 for seeing that posts). Now, when I begin to edit that article (as you asked me in the question), I find 'categories on the right side as it supposed to be and it is no doubt have tick marks on the respected categories which my client needed. When I click on update. The questions are moving to the url `fatwaa.com/questions/post-title`. Whereas, when you look at the categories, you found zero posts.

I then soon back posted a test article in the 'Post' Section by ticking mark the respected category then without any difficulty I'm getting that in the category. I have edited one archive and tick mark one category into that and it is working without any difficulty.

So, I think the whole problem is causing due to this 'Questions Template'.

Also on the home page whenever I go to any category it is displaying same posts again and again..

(here is the code of the home page) http://pastebin.com/5LqnwAzY

Answer (score 1):

If the Categories referred to here are the WordPress native `category` taxonomy, the queries for these term pages by default will only include the native `post` post type.

To add custom post types to category term queries, you can add a bit of code to your theme's `functions.php` file, which modifies these queries via the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to add your custom post type:

```
function wpa_category_custom_type( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'questions' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_category_custom_type' );
```

The above assumes your post type is registered as `questions`.

Comment: Well it didn't work either and I'm still unable to see any posts via category (which is posted via custom_post_type 'questions').Well I just want to ask that will custom post type also uses permalink? If so, then is it its problem?

Comment: In the code you linked, you refer to the post type as `question`, singular, not `questions` plural. did you change the code above to correctly reference your post type as `question`?

Comment: also, [read this question/answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Comment: Yes, I even tried by using 'question'. Well, one more thing is that it is definitely working with 'Posts'. I mean if we directly go to the posts and from there if we post and give categories then it is defintely working. Please find the function.php code here http://pastebin.com/R849Nhpk